# grep -o regex with 2 possibilities

Tags: regex, grep

I have this list of strings:

```
Image.aarch64-1.0-Default-Build15.raw.xz
Image.aarch64-1.0-Default-Build15.raw.xz.sha256
Image.aarch64-1.0-Default-Build15.raw.xz.sha256.asc
Image.s390x-1.0-Default-base1-Build15.raw.xz
Image.s390x-1.0-Default-base1-Build15.raw.xz.sha256
Image.s390x-1.0-Default-base1-Build15.raw.xz.sha256.asc
Image.s390x-1.0-Default-base2-Build15.raw.xz
Image.s390x-1.0-Default-base2-Build15.raw.xz.sha256
Image.s390x-1.0-Default-base2-Build15.raw.xz.sha256.asc
Image.s390x-1.0-Default-base3-Build15.qcow2
Image.s390x-1.0-Default-base3-Build15.qcow2.sha256
Image.s390x-1.0-Default-base3-Build15.qcow2.sha256.asc
Image.x86_64-1.0-Default-Build15.raw.xz
Image.x86_64-1.0-Default-Build15.raw.xz.sha256
Image.x86_64-1.0-Default-Build15.raw.xz.sha256.asc
Image.x86_64-1.0-Default-RT-Build15.raw.xz
Image.x86_64-1.0-Default-RT-Build15.raw.xz.sha256
Image.x86_64-1.0-Default-RT-Build15.raw.xz.sha256.asc
```

and I need to exclude where `base1` and `base2` is in the string and also remove the tails `sha256` and `sha256.asc` and I am limited to do this with `grep -o` only. Any hints?

Comment: Did you try writing any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this regex:

```
^(?!.*?base1)(?!.*?base2).*?(?=(?:\.sha256(?:\.asc)?)?$)
```

[As seen here at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Xbm9CP/1)

## Explanation:

`^` matches the start of the string
`(?!.*?base1)` and `(?!.*?base2)` are similar, they use a negative lookahead to make sure there isn't a base1 or base2 anywhere in the string after 0 or more characters
`(?=(?:\.sha256(?:\.asc)?)?$)` is a bit lengthy, but I assure you it's easy to decipher.

We tell the regex that this position should be followed by an optional `.sha256` which might have an option `.asc` appended to it. Regardless of whether this whole optional ending exists, the match must end with a line-ending `$`

A non-capturing group is denoted by `(?:)`, which means that regex should match whatever is in brackets like normal, but should not specifically capture it in a separate group.

To denote something that is optional, we add a `?` at the end. This actually means `0 or 1`, which logically translates to being optional.
So we accomplish the ending part using an optional, non-capturing group `(?:\.sha256(?:\.asc)?)?`.

As you can see, .asc is also an optional, non-capturing group, and this is to make sure that IF a `.sha256` is encountered, we must also consider if it ends with `.asc`.

Comment: Thanks! I also found another way using "or" in the expression `Image.*-Default-Build.*\.raw\.xz$\|Image.*-Default-base3-Build.*\.qcow2$`
So I specify which extension I get for each case.